# Eventos duplicados en fullcalendar al cancelar y volver a introducir un evento

Tags: fullcalendar

estoy tratando de hacer una agenda que está conectada con un programa que había hecho y que ya estaba funcionando. Cuando se hace click en un hueco en donde no hay ningún evento (dateClick), sale un modal para rellenar una serie de datos y después enviarlos a una página u otra según sea un paciente antiguo o un paciente nuevo.

Hasta aquí funciona todo bien, pero cuando hago click en un hueco y después cancelo, bien sea con el botón de cancelar, con la "x" o clicando fuera del modal, y después pongo otra cita, me mete tantas citas como haya hecho click y cancelado previamente.

He probado varias cosas, como [Esto de aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery), o a hacer `$('#enviar_cita').empty();`, pero nada me funciona... Pego el código del dateclick:

```
dateClick: function(info) { //Click en un sitio sin cita
            var ahora=new Date();
            var fecha_evento = new Date(moment(info.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
            if(fecha_evento>ahora){ //No se pueden poner eventos en el pasado
                $('#ponerCita').modal();
                moment.locale('es');
                $('#modalTitle').html('Nueva cita: ' + moment(info.date).format('dddd DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'));
                $('#poner_comentario').hide();
                $('#mostrar_comentario').click(function(){
                    $('#poner_comentario').show();
                    $('#mostrar_comentario').hide();
                });
                $('#enviar_cita').click(function(){ //Para poner una cita nueva
                    var paciente=$("#paciente_nombre").val();
                    var fecha=moment(info.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                    var hora=moment(info.date).format('HH');
                    var minuto=moment(info.date).format('mm');
                    var usuario=$("#terapeuta").val();
                    var importe=$("#importe").val();
                    var domicilio=($("#domicilio").is(":checked"))?1:0;
                    var relajacion=($("#relajacion").is(":checked"))?1:0;
                    var iva=($("#iva").is(":checked"))?1:0;
                    var media=($("#media").is(":checked"))?1:0;
                    var grupo=($("#grupo").is(":checked"))?1:0;
                    var grupox=$("#grupox").val();
                    var nuevo=($("#nuevo").is(":checked"))?1:0;
                    var comentario=$('#comentario').val();
                    if(nuevo==1){
                        var pagina = "intro_cita_nuevo.php";
                    }else{
                        var pagina = "intro_cita.php";
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: pagina,
                        data: "pac="+paciente+"&fec="+fecha+"&hor="+hora+"&min="+minuto+"&usu="+usuario+"&imp="+importe+"&dom="+domicilio+"&rel="+relajacion+"&iva="+iva+"&med="+media+"&gru="+grupo+"&grx="+grupox+"&nue="+nuevo+"&com="+comentario,
                        cache: false,
                        success:function(result){
                            $('#ponerCita').modal('hide');
                            $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
                                $("#Formulario1")[0].reset();
                            });
                            $('#enviar_cita').off();
                            calendar.refetchEvents();
                        }
                    });
                });
                $('#ponerCita').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e){
                    $('#Formulario1')[0].reset();
                    $('#mostrar_comentario').show();
                });
            }

          },
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería mucho, porque llevo ya un tiempo intentando solucionar esto y no doy con ello. Si alguien necesita más información o que muestre algún trozo de código más, por favor, que me lo diga.
Muchas gracias.

ACTUALIZO:
Me da la sensación de que cada vez que hago click en el calendario, se guarda en un array o algo parecido. Haciendo `console.log(Object.values(info));` me sale:

```
prueba.php:138 (6) [Wed Mar 11 2020 09:00:00 GMT+0100 (hora estándar de Europa central), "2020-03-11T09:00:00+01:00", false, td.fc-day.fc-wed.fc-future, MouseEvent, TimeGridView]
prueba.php:138 (6) [Wed Mar 11 2020 09:00:00 GMT+0100 (hora estándar de Europa central), "2020-03-11T09:00:00+01:00", false, td.fc-day.fc-wed.fc-future, MouseEvent, TimeGridView]
prueba.php:138 (6) [Thu Mar 12 2020 08:30:00 GMT+0100 (hora estándar de Europa central), "2020-03-12T08:30:00+01:00", false, td.fc-day.fc-thu.fc-future, MouseEvent, TimeGridView]
```

Pero no sé cómo resetear ese array.

Comment: Puedes explicar como  "me mete tantas citas como haya hecho click y cancelado previamente." . Podrías hacer un `console.log()` con tus datos que se están repitiendo por favor. Todo esto en tu pregunta, puedes editar la pregunta agregando la forma en como se te esta mostrando tu código.

Comment: Si, con eso me refiero a que si, por ejemplo, hago click y luego cancelo en el miércoles a las 8, el jueves a las 10, el viernes a las 11 y finalmente le doy a enviar en un último evento el sábado a las 8, me introduce citas en todas y cada una de las fechas. Si hubiese clicado más veces, pues más eventos me habría creado. Lo del console.log(), no sé dónde tengo que hacerlo.

Comment: Lo del console.log hazlo dentro del dateClick, `console.log(info.date)` o también `console.log(fecha_evento);` solo para verificar que estas obteniendo del calendario.

Comment: Desde la consola de tu navegador, verifica cuantas peticiones estas realizando hacía tu archivo.php.

Comment: Con ```console.log(info.date)``` me sale:
```Wed Mar 11 2020 08:00:00 GMT+0100 (hora estándar de Europa central)
prueba.php:117 Thu Mar 12 2020 08:00:00 GMT+0100 (hora estándar de Europa central)```. Hace tantas peticiones a intro_cita.php como eventos introduce, en este caso 2.

Comment: `$("#enviar_cita").on("click", function (event) {` modifica esto por lo que tienes.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo @Isai Maldonado Lo he modificado por lo que me pones, pero sigue funcionando igual.

Comment: Podrías hacer cada vez que le de click en el evento dateClick se ponga en blanco el campo de paciente, `$("#paciente_nombre").val('');`, luego cuando sea el click, hagas una validación `if($("#paciente_nombre").val() !== '')` solo como una pequeña prueba

Comment: Hay un evento que se llama `select` podrías intentar con el (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback)

Comment: El if tampoco funciona, sigue haciendo lo que hacía. En cuanto al ```select``` sirve para arrastrar en el calendario y por razones de usabilidad no lo puedo utilizar. Lo que si que es curioso es que los datos que se introducen todas las veces son los de la que se envía con el botón, exceptuando la fecha y hora, que en cada uno son distintos.

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que cada vez que te sales de algún modal, esté, no se elimina por completo.
Las fechas se almacenan localmente por modal, en cambio, el resto de los inputs solo respetan al ultimo modal, ya que se manejan por ID.

Como observación, puedes revisar desde el inspector de código HTML de tu navegador y buscar **modalTitle** o algún otro ID que se repita por modal.

Comment: He inspeccionado el código en le navegador y nada. Pero me da la sensación de que cada vez que hago click en el calendario, se guarda en un array o algo parecido. Actualizo y pego código.

Comment: Para resetear un array solo basta con `info.length = 0;` puedes hacer un var_dump($_GET); en tu archivo .php para ver que estas mandando desde tu js.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que yo creo que el problema está en la página del calendario, porque el código que puse en la actualización me lo pone antes de enviar nada. En el primer click ```console.log(Object.values(info));``` muestra la primera línea (```prueba.php:138 (6) [Wed Mar 11 2020 09:00:00 GMT+0100 (hora estándar de Europa central), "2020-03-11T09:00:00+01:00", false, td.fc-day.fc-wed.fc-future, MouseEvent, TimeGridView]```), y en el segundo click pone la segunda y la tercera, es decir la que corresponde y la anterior (como que hay dos eventos)

Comment: Una forma un poco chapucera de solucionarlo es poniendo ```location.reload();``` en ```$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {``` Al recargar la página, sólo envía un evento. Muchas gracias de todas formas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambiando un poco el enfoque del problema, creo que ya he dado con una solución, anulo la fecha del evento si se sale del modal, con lo que sólo envía el que es enviado con el botón, ya que el resto no tiene fecha:

```
$('#ponerCita').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e){
    $('#Formulario1')[0].reset();
    $('#mostrar_comentario').show();
    info.date=null;
});
```

Con esto dentro de `dateclick:`, da igual los clicks que se hagan previamente, que sólo se envía el evento que se manda con el botón.